# Promise returns empty list

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird, cheerio

I have written a function that gets a list of hyperlink anchors through webscraping.

I want to push all these anchors onto an object array, which will later be serialized to a Json string.

The `Api.GetCourseSubmenuUrl` method and the `Api.FilterSubmenuContentList` both return promises.

The following code however keeps running without waiting for the array to be filled in the `.each()` cheerio function. Why does this happen?

*Please note that the each method in cheerio is synchronous.*

**My code uses the packages:**

- Bluebird (https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird)
- Cheerio (https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio)
- Request (https://github.com/request/request)

**Code:**

```
Connection.prototype.FillCourseWithSubmenuContent = function(course){
    var self = this; //This class
    var submenuItems = [];
    return new BPromise(function(resolve, reject){
      return Api.GetCourseSubmenuUrl(ApiConnection.authToken).then(function(response){
        return request.get({url: self.url + response.url + course.id, followRedirect: false, jar: cookiejar}, function(err,httpResponse,body){
          if(err){
            reject(err);
          }
          var cheerio = require('cheerio');
          var dashboardhtml = cheerio.load(body, {
                  normalizeWhitespace: true,
                  decodeEntities: true
              }
          );
          //Find all the links on the page
          dashboardhtml('a').each(function(i, elem) {
              console.log("Object:");
              console.log({"text":dashboardhtml(elem).text(), "url":dashboardhtml(elem).attr('href')});
              submenuItems.push({"text":dashboardhtml(elem).text().trim(), "url":dashboardhtml(elem).attr('href')});
          });
          resolve();
        });
      }).then(function(){
        console.log(submenuItems);
        return Api.FilterSubmenuContentList(ApiConnection.authToken, submenuItems);
      });
    }).catch(function(error){
      return reject(error);
    });
};
```

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: That `reject` function you're calling is not even in scope.

Comment: @Bergi I don't really grasp how the antipattern appies to my code? Where does it go wrong? Is it the usage of a promise within a promise? You're talking about the first or second reject?

Comment: Yes, the usage of promises within the `Promise` callback. And the second `reject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was fixed by taking the `Promise constructor antipattern` into account, pointed out by @Bergi.

Since the Request library doesn't have promise support, I still had to wrap it inside a (Bluebird) promise.

*Please note that it is also possible to `promisify` libraries, which makes life a lot easier. But for the demonstration of the solution I went the promise wrapping route.*

**The solution:**

```
Connection.prototype.FillCourseWithSubmenuContent = function(course){
    var self = this; //This class
    var submenuItems = [];
    return Api.GetCourseSubmenuUrl(ApiConnection.authToken).then(function(response){
      console.log(self.url + response.url + course.id);
      return new BPromise(function(resolve, reject){
        request.get({url: self.url + response.url + course.id, followRedirect: false, jar: cookiejar}, function(err,httpResponse,body){
          if(err){
            reject(err);
          }
          var cheerio = require('cheerio');
          var dashboardhtml = cheerio.load(body, {
                  normalizeWhitespace: true,
                  decodeEntities: true
              }
          );
          //Find all the links on the page
          dashboardhtml('a').each(function(i, elem) {
              // console.log("Object");
              // console.log({"text":dashboardhtml(elem).text(), "url":dashboardhtml(elem).attr('href')});
              submenuItems.push({"text":dashboardhtml(elem).text().trim(), "url":dashboardhtml(elem).attr('href')});
          });
          return resolve();
        });
      });
    }).then(function(){
      console.log(submenuItems);
      return Api.FilterSubmenuContentList(ApiConnection.authToken, submenuItems);
    });
};
```

Comment: +1, this is what I meant. I would have even gone as far as doing `resolve(body)`, and putting the `cheerio` stuff into a `then` handler where exceptions will automatically be caught